# VS CPP projects: is it possible to link DLL to form one exe-file

Tags: dll, mfc, static-linking

I have two Visual Studio C++ projects - a dialog based application and a DLL.
The DLL is used by the first application. 
I want to have the DLL statically linked with the first application to form one **monolite** executable file. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to statically link a DLL into an exe. You can change the DLL project into a lib project and link the lib.